# ?? (null coalescing) vs ? (ternary if) expression

Tags: c#, .net

Please, look at that sample code:

```
short? myNullableShort = 5;
short myShort = 0;

// It works
myShort = myNullableShort ?? 0;

// It doesn't work, Compiler error
// Cannot implicitly convert type 'short?' to 'short'. 
// An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  
myShort = myNullableShort != null ? myNullableShort : 0;
```

I can understand why is the second one not working. But, I would expect that the first one will cause the compiler error, but it isn't.

My question is that, *why the first one works fine?*

Comment: Why would you expect an error? The expectation should be whatever the spec says. And the spec says that "default" values get promoted to nullable versions as needed. Which is kind of obvious because a) it would be cumbersome to do it manually as it's done with the ternary and b) the compiler can easily and unambiguously guess what your intention is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myNullableShort ?? 0` works like `myNullableShort != null ? myNullableShort.Value : 0`. That is, the `?:`'s middle operand is an expression of type `short`, not `short?`.

But if you want to avoid using `??`, a more readable way of writing it than with `?:` is `myNullableShort.GetValueOrDefault()`, or the slightly more verbose `myNullableShort.GetValueOrDefault(0)`.

Actually, that `myNullableShort.GetValueOrDefault()` will be used behind the scenes by the compiler when you write `myNullableShort ?? 0`: `a ?? b` gets translated to `a.HasValue ? a.GetValueOrDefault() : b`, as a micro-optimisation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you happen to know *why* it uses `GetValueOrDefault()`? Seems to me that the `OrDefault` part will never execute. I did confirm that it does compile to what you said it does, but I'm still curious as to why it doesn't compile to `a.HasValue ? a.Value : b` instead.

Comment: @Rob The `Nullable<T>` type is defined (in part) as roughly `public struct Nullable<T> { private bool hasValue; private T value; public bool HasValue { get { return hasValue; } } public T GetValueOrDefault() { return value; } public T Value { get { if (!hasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException(); return value; } } }` The `GetValueOrDefault()` function returns the `value` field directly, the `Value` property has added logic to throw exceptions, so avoiding that extra logic where it isn't needed gives a small speed improvement.

Answer (score 1):

When you reach the line :

```
myShort = myNullableShort != null ? myNullableShort : 0;
```

myNullableShort is still a nullable, and you can't cast a nullable to a non-nullable.

try this:

```
myShort = myNullableShort.HasValue ? myNullableShort.Value : 0;
```

the first one works because you can assign a nullable a value from a non-nullable, and `myNullableShort ?? 0` is guaranteed to return either the value of `myNullableShort` (if present) or `0`